# Member property as default value for method

Tags: c++, c++11, default-value

I've a header file which looks like the following

```
#ifndef BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_H
#define BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_H

struct Node
{
  int data;
  Node *left, *right;
  Node(int data);
};

class BinarySearchTree
{
  Node *head;
 public:
  BinarySearchTree();
  void insert(int data);
  void inorder(Node *cur = head);
};

#endif
```

and It says

```
In file included from Binary_Search_Tree.cpp:2:0:
Binary_Search_Tree.h:17:28: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘BinarySearchTree::head’
   void inorder(Node *cur = head);
                            ^
Binary_Search_Tree.h:13:9: note: declared here
   Node *head;
```

Note: I've not provided the default value while defining the method. I guess that isn't necessary.

Only static or constant values are allowed for default values ? if yes then why ?
Or something else is wrong ?

Comment: Fyi, at least the *behavior* you seek is easily doable with an added overload of `void inorder() { inorder(head); };`

Comment: yeah, that can be done, then what is the usefulness of default value in c++. python doesn't support overloading and the above case can be fairly done with only single method instead of two using default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you're looking for can't be done in C++. The default value has to be "somewhat constant". That means an actual constant, or a static field etc. There's more info [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) about what is allowed and not for default arguments.

---

One way to solve this issue is to have an overload without any arguments which just calls the one-argument function starting at `head`.
Another is to use null as the default argument and replace it with head when provided. This might break if you reach null leaf nodes, though.

Answer (score 2):

A quote from the standard (draft):

> A non-static member shall not appear in a default argument unless it appears as the id-expression of a class member access expression ([expr.ref]) or unless it is used to form a pointer to member ([expr.unary.op])

---

> Note: I've not provided the default value while defining the method. I guess that isn't necessary.

It isn't even allowed to redefine a default argument in a redeclaration (which a definition of a previously declared function is).

> Only static or constant values are allowed for default values ?

No. Non-constant values are allowed as well. But there are many exceptions, and members are included in the exceptions.

---

You can work around the limitation by using an overload.

Comment: can you provide a link as to say which are allowed and which are not ?